# why shift + f10 not working in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have noticed that some of the Chrome instances with same version "35.0.1916.153 m" open browser context menu on click of SHIFT+F10 but some instances not open browser context menu.

Is there any key map setting needs to be done for this? If yes, can some one please let me know how to do that?Thanks in Advance.